# Swagger UI require fails in Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, swagger-ui

I have a Node.js application using Electron v15.3.1. I embed a Swagger UI for viewing OAS files. The Swagger UI version I am using is 4.6.1. It now has a security vulnerability so I need to upgrade it.

I first tried to run `npm audit fix` which ran successfully, but after that the Swagger UI fails at time when i require it:

```
let SwaggerUI = require('swagger-ui')
```

With this error printed in the console of Chrome Dev Tools:

```
VM67 node:vm:108 Uncaught /Users/benjaminmogensen/workspace/API-JSON-Schema-Definitions/node_modules/react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/light.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global, Buffer) { return function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import highlight from './highlight';
                                                                                                                                                           ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at new Script (node:vm:100:7)
    at createScript (node:vm:257:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:305:10)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:982:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:823:12)
    at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
    at Function.o._load (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:29:379)
```

Next, I tried to upgrade to latest version 4.9.0, instead of running `npm audit fix`. After updating the `package.json` file and running `npm install` it's the same result.

I then tried all other versions from 4.6.1 up to 4.9.0 and its the same result. I then tried a previous version - same result.

I have also tried to do a `npm cache verify`.

**However**, when I revert to version 4.6.1 and do `npm install` it works again.

Any help, very much appreciated!

Comment: It's possibly this issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7944

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the electron framework. Unless you have no issue reverting to your old version. I suggest you try [this](https://medium.com/@pativancarrasco/why-your-es6-syntax-doesnt-work-in-node-js-and-how-to-fix-it-161f0708f1ad) solution.

Babel basically is supposed to bring back the old syntax including stuff such as `import`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure how to use this for solving the issue. The version 4.6.1 is working and has been working for a long time event across multiple Electron versions. So I am puzzled why it suddenly does not work when upgrading Swagger UI. I have not changed the way I require the Swagger UI at all.